# .How does the Android GPS work?

Tags: android, gps

I'd like to understand a bit better the way GPS works in Android and I'd like to include some traces to track it and modify its behavior. In GpsLocationProvider.java I found the methods:

```
 private native boolean native_init();
private native void native_disable();
private native void native_cleanup();
private native boolean native_start(int positionMode, boolean singleFix, int fixInterval);
private native boolean native_stop();
private native void native_set_fix_frequency(int fixFrequency);
private native void native_delete_aiding_data(int flags);
private native void native_wait_for_event();
// returns number of SVs
// mask[0] is ephemeris mask and mask[1] is almanac mask
private native int native_read_sv_status(int[] svs, float[] snrs,
        float[] elevations, float[] azimuths, int[] masks);
private native int native_read_nmea(int index, byte[] buffer, int bufferSize);
private native void native_inject_location(double latitude, double longitude, float accuracy);

// XTRA Support
private native void native_inject_time(long time, long timeReference, int uncertainty);
private native boolean native_supports_xtra();
private native boolean native_inject_xtra_data(byte[] data, int length);

// DEBUG Support
private native String native_get_internal_state();

// AGPS Support
private native void native_agps_data_conn_open(String apn);
private native void native_agps_data_conn_closed();
private native void native_agps_data_conn_failed();
private native void native_set_agps_server(int type, String hostname, int port);

// Network-initiated (NI) Support
private native void native_send_ni_response(int notificationId, int userResponse);
```

However, I would like to see what they do in detail. Where are they implemented? I've found the qualcomm drivers for GPS but I guess that there's a missing layer in between where the hardware issues are abstracted (HAL layer?).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are aware that these are supposed to be mapped at the JNI layer to corresponding GPS vendor APIs. You are right when you say that these are implemented as part of HAL layer. The HAL layer will be part of GPS chipset Vendor code.

Since you spoke about qualcomm, I can tell you that qualcomm has the HAL layer for sure. You can check their engine part if you have their source. But it has copyrights & hence, I cannot give you the source code which implements the native APIs.